# ClickOnce deployment with Roslyn assemblies: manifest version mismatch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, roslyn

I'm trying to deploy a Clickonce application that refercences the Roselyn assemblies through Nuget packages.

The **Roslyn Nuget packages have version 1.2.20906.2** but:

1. When I look at the dll properties in the `packages` folder I see
   **the DLLs have version 1.2.20906.1**
2. When I look at the **references** properties in the VS2012 **Solution Explorer**, it shows **version 1.2.0.0** (the path points to the Nuget package dll)

**`Local copy`** is set to true as is **`Specific version`** for all Roslyn references.

When I publish my clickonce, **the Dll included and deployed have version 1.2.20906.1** but the Clickonce manifest states:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="Roslyn.Services.dll" size="1345672">
        <assemblyIdentity name="Roslyn.Services" version="1.2.0.0" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
...
```

So version in the manifest is 1.2.0.0.

When I try to install the Clickonce on the client, I get an error message (translated from french): `Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Roslyn.Services.dll`

The client machine is Windows 7 x86.

I tried to target **AnyCPU** and  **x86** in my VS project without success.

When I deploy via xcopy on the target machine, the app runs fine.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about the specific ClickOnce issue, but I will point out that file version and assembly version are completely independent, and it's quite common for them to be different.  In fact, every assembly that is part of VS or .Net have file versions different from the assembly version.

Comment: @KevinPilch-Bisson: Thanks for the comment. I was actually wondering because for the other references in my project there was a match between the file version and the assembly versions in the ClickOnce manifest. Also I wonder if this issue is specific to me and if other people have been able to do a successfull ClickOnce deployment including latest Roslyn assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the reference in VS point to? Does it point to the packages folder? If not, it should, since that's the assembly you want to deploy. You should delete the reference and re-add it, pointing to the one with the version you want to deploy. It might be accessing the old version in the GAC and then publishing the new version, which won't work. ClickOnce is very specific, and the versions must match.

Comment: It points to the Nuget package but I'm suspecting that the GAC version is deployed anyway. How could I verify this?

Comment: A local reference takes precedence over the GAC, assuming the assembly is not required to be in the GAC to be used. For example, DirectX can be local, but SQLExpress cannot. I think it's just not pointing where you think it's pointing. For grins, copy the dll you want to use into the same folder as the project and add it to the project and add a reference to it. See if that works. If it does, then your initial version is not accessing what you think it's accessing.

Comment: I did some additional checking: the problem is not with the deployed dll because the clickonce deployed dll are the good ones (the ones from the NuGet package). The problem is with the version clickonce thinks it should deploy. (So something wrong in the manifest...?)